# AJAX/JS: Is it possible to grab value of input text without a submit button and refesh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have searched countless of sites but havent come upon a definite answer. Maybe this is not possible. But I am working with an input box that will echo its value once the user stops typing. I dont have relevant code since I want to find out if this possible?

Here in this example I can submit trhrough a button and get the value without a refresh.
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MswhY/3/)

But I would like to be able to not use the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's possible with a script, onkeyup and a timer](http://jsfiddle.net/MswhY/4/).

Basically what you do is when a user starts typing, you fire up a timer for a submit function. Every time the user presses a key when the input is focused, you "postpone" the timer by clearing it and creating it again. Once the user stops typing, the timer won't be cleared and the function will run.

```
var timer;

$('#yourName').on('keyup', function() {
    var value = this.value;

    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {

        //do your submit here
        alert('submitted:' + value);

    }, 2000); //delay after a keypress
});​
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 10 seconds. Mine was identical. :D

Comment: I use this same approach to check if the receiving user is currently online. My timeout is half a second

Comment: +1 tahnk you i been looking for this. Would it be possible to submit the whole form once the user finishes typing in the input box?

Comment: @cholomanCoding yes. You can take a refence of the form and programatically submit it using `submit()`